# ZooKeeper C Library issue

Tags: c, hadoop, shared-libraries, static-libraries, apache-zookeeper

I previously made a [post asking on the installation of zookeeper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51255329/zookeeper-c-binding-installation?noredirect=1#comment89490736_51255329). I decided to just send the library files and zookeeper source files along with my code to the second device in hopes to compile it with gcc.

After creating a directory for the user/local/lib files such as libzookeeper_mt.a and the rest. I also created a directory for my code where I would just link the zookeeper library upon compilation. Navigating to the directory in which my code was saved, I typed this into the command line:

```
gcc -Wall main.c -o test -L/workspace/zookeeper/lib -lzookeeper_mt -std=c99
```

This should link my code to the zookeeper libraries as it works on my local computer, but not on the computer I sent the files to. Here is the error I am getting:

```
-bash-4.0$ gcc -Wall  main.c -o test  -L/workspace/zookeeper/lib 
-lzookeeper_mt -std=c99  
In file included from main.c:3:
zookeeper.h:309: warning: declaration does not declare anything
ld: warning: file /workspace/zookeeper/lib/libzookeeper_mt.a 
ignored: unable to locate archive symbol table
ld: fatal: library -lzookeeper_mt: not found
ld: fatal: file processing errors. No output written to test
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Why is the library being ignored? I tried researching it and I was told to ranlib the library. I tried indexing all the zookeeper _st and _mt files to the libzookeeper_mt.a and it didn't work.

Comment: But `gcc -Wall main.c -o test /workspace/zookeeper/lib/libzookeeper_mt.a -std=c99` works?

Comment: no it doesn't same error is given. Sorry i didn't notice -o main was there instead of -o test

Comment: Have you build the library with `ar cru libzookeeper_mt.a all.o object.o files.o that.o belong.o in.o libzoo.o` followed by a `ranlib libzookeeper_mt.a`?

Comment: I can unarchive the files on my Mac from the libzookeeper_mt.a to give me all the .o files that belong to libzookeeper_mt.a . Should I send those files over to my secondary device and ranlib them together into libzookeeper_mt.a? (There is also a __.SYMDEF SORTED file.. will that go into ranlib? i'll try it anyways)

Comment: It might be that the sytem on your second device is slightly different, so it is an idea to move all `*.o` to that system, and run the two commands I listed above there.

Comment: After running ar cru libzookeeper_mt.a hashtable.o hashtable_itr.o . . . (and the rest of .o files) and then running ranlib libzookeeper_mt.a. I tried navigating back to my main.c and running the gcc and got the same error. I'll try deleting the libzookeeper_mt.a and trying the ranlib after deleting it.

Comment: Sadly deleting libzookeeper_mt.a and replacing it with a fresh copy of it and then running the ar cru libzookeeper_mt.a <all .o files>  and then running ranlib libzookeeper_mt.a did not work.

Comment: I peeked into the building of `libzookeeper_mt.a` (version 3.4.12) and it is a bit more complicated than that although not much. The simplest way is probably to install it to your second device from the original build-directory. Go to `zookeeper-3.4.12/src/c/` (adjust version-number) and do a `make distclean && ./configure --prefix=/workspace/zookeeper/ --libdir=/workspace/zookeeper/lib && make install;` It should make both, the static and the dynamic library, you can switch one off with `./configure` with `--disable-static` or `--disable-shared` respectively.

Comment: The make install brings a whole other issue I posted in one of my other posts, but slightly different error msg. 
'mt.so -lnsl -lsocket -lm -lpthread -R/workspace/kunalp/zookeeper/lib
Undefined                       first referenced
 symbol                           in file
__sync_fetch_and_add      ./.libs/libzookeeper_mt.so
ld: fatal: symbol referencing errors. No output written to .libs/cli_mt
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
*** Error code 1
make: Fatal error: Command failed for target `cli_mt' '

This the error I was trying to avoid by moving all files and including library.

Comment: If you base your question on another post: please put a link to it.

Comment: link is hyperlinked to where I mentioned it on my question. I will remember to do so next time. Here it is in the comments for convenience: 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51255329/zookeeper-c-binding-installation?noredirect=1#comment89490736_51255329

Comment: Link is to the comment 'Are you actually running "i386-pc-solaris2.11"?' so I assume the client needs to run under Solaris. According to https://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.4.12/zookeeperAdmin.html#sc_supportedPlatforms the client is not supported for Solaris.

Comment: @deamentiaemundi That is probably the issue.. I hope not. Then again I am running it fine on Mac so the C client is working. I am not using multiple servers nor am I trying to connect to an ensemble.